# changing background image to be random

Tags: java, android, random

Let's say I have a couple of background pictures for my apps main screen. Each time when the app starts I'd like the background pic to be randomly chosen, is that possible in android ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer:

```
private static final int NUM_BACKGROUNDS = 5; // or whatever
private Random mRandom = new Random();

public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    View v = findViewById(/* your background view id */);
    int res;
    int i = mRandom.nextInt(NUM_BACKGROUNDS);
    switch (i) {
        case 0: res = R.drawable.bg0; break;
        case 1: res = R.drawable.bg1; break;
        case 2: res = R.drawable.bg2; break;
        case 3: res = R.drawable.bg3; break;
        case 4: res = R.drawable.bg4; break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("oops?");
    }
    v.setBackgroundResource(res);
}
```

Comment: I have an error: The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: s/setBackgroundDrawable()/setBackgroundResource()/. changed it already in the answer.